# Ember property binding doesn't work with object

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember and trying to understand why the binding is not working here:
http://jsbin.com/mogar/5/edit

I want the bound isAuthenticated to show the state of the value. What am I doing wrong there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the controller's context `this` and setter so that the bindings can properly update. So update your action to be:

```
actions: {
  login: function () {
    this.set('isAuthenticated', true);
  },
  logout: function() {
    this.set('isAuthenticated', false);
  }
}
```

Example JSBin: http://jsbin.com/loboyehe/1/edit